# Can I use Redstone underwater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Fairly simple question: Do redstone dust/redstone torches/switches/etc. work underwater?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope, you can't place them on tiles with water, they pop back up. If you have placed them already and water flows over them then they will do the same.

**Bonus edit:**

Here's a picture of me trying to place a redstone torch down, while a sheep looks on in bewilderment:

[image]

Comment: You can only place them in air blocks.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if you make a tunnel. Here's some images of me doing just this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well... Sticky piston plus Redstone blocks. Expensive, but no tunnels needed.

Comment: This is a good answer, but could you please provide some screenshots so readers can see what you are describing?

Answer (score 1):

Redstone can't be placed underwater without a mod.  Check out the [mod forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewforum.php?f=1032) or [Minecraft Mod Center](http://www.mcmodcenter.net/).